# how to uninstall chainfire3d with adb ? (Android)

Tags: android, adb, uninstallation

I installed chainfire3d on my new tablet, but it crashed and got into a bootloop.
Thankfully for me, adb can connect to it, so I am trying to uninstall chainfire3d with adb.
I tried :

```
adb uninstall eu.chainfire.cf3d
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d package:eu.chainfire.cf3d
adb shell pm uninstall -k eu.chainfire.cf3d
```

They all gave the same error :

```
soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libandroid_runtime.so" needed by "app_process"; caused by soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libhwui.so" needed by "libandroid_runtime.so"; caused by soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "glInsertEventMarketEXT" referenced by "libhwui.so"...CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

So I went another way :

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system
rm -r /system/app/[AppName].apk
```

But I searched in my other tablet what is the name of chainfire3d's apk file and I did not find it here.

Please help me : How can I uninstall chainfire3d with adb ?

Comment: The name of the APK should be Chainfire3D_Pro_v3.3 MXFB.apk Version might differ depending on which one you installed but this should point you in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Follow [this tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVXX-YdhRU0) to install and open a program which you will use to **uninstall** the driver of ChainFire installed on your device.
> 2. Start your phone into recovery mode (Home + Vol up + Power).
> 3. Plug in your phone via USB cord to your computer.
> 4. Once you have ADB opened in command prompt, type `su` to gain superuser access.
> 5. After that, you type `cd /system/lib`
> 6. Then you type `cf3d_uninstall.sh`

Source: [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2362873)